# Iteration with constants and other variables with Arrays Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, math

I am trying to modify the function below so that it gives the expected output below. For the first calculation it go like `100+ 100*-87/100 = 13` with the equation `NonC_Amount  + Int_amount  * np.cumprod(PnL / 100)`. Since -87 is the first element in the PnL, for the second calculation it will go as `13 + 100*-4/100 = 9`. the NonC_Amounts value is updated.

```
PnL = np.array([-87., -4., -34.1, 8.5])
Int_amount = 100
NonC_Amount = 100
PnL.prod(initial=Int_amount)
NonCompounding =NonC_Amount  + Int_amount  * np.cumprod(PnL / 100)
```

Current Output:

```
[ 13, 103.48 , 98.81332,  99.8991322]
```

Expected Output:

```
[ 13,  9,  -25.1,  -16.6]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do the wrong calculations. From your description it seems you want to do

```
NonC_Amount = 100
NonCompounding = np.zeros_like(PnL)
for i in range(PnL.shape[0]):
    NonCompounding[i] = NonC_Amount + Int_amount * PnL[i] / 100
    NonC_Amount = NonCompounding[i]
```

**Edit**: If you want this operation vectorised, you can do

```
NonCompounding = NonC_Amount + np.cumsum(Int_amount * PnL / 100)
```

---

`np.cumprod()` gives you the cumulative product up to the ith element. For `np.cumprod(PnL)` that'd be

```
[-87, -87*(-4), -87*(-4)*(-34.1), etc...]
```

and it's only by pure chance it gives you the correct result for the first element.

Comment: I have updated the issue sorry about the mistake it was supposed to be -16. instead of 16. if possible I am trying to avoid for loops as they are slow and inefficient.